# How to retrive a Tikz code

Tags: tikz-pgf, inkscape

> I would like to produce an illustration drawing for my course notes, but I am totally ignorant in vector drawing software. I installed Inkscape and I would like to 'produce' from a pdf image, a vectorialized one from which I can recover the tikz code.
>   Here is the drawing. Can you tell me some ways to reach a nice tikz code?
>   Thank you!

[image]

Comment: I do not think you will get a *nice* Ti*k*Z code from inkscape and company. If you already have the pdf, you can just include it in your presentation. If you want to have a nice Ti*k*Z code, you probably need to learn how to use it. The above diagram is not very difficult to obtain, but perhaps a bit tedious.

Comment: Off-topic, but it is always fine to ask your instructor for source code. Specify what you want (the figure on page X) so they can give you the fragment if they decide not to disclose the whole document.

Comment: Thanks @Schrödinger'scat for your suggestions!

Comment: Thanks @Symbol1